# .focus() and email function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to jquery, php and ajax and was writing this code with the help of a colleague.

My code:

```
if( name == '' ){
    alert("Please enter your name");
    $("#name", first).focus();
    status = 'N';
}
else {
    status = 'Y';
};

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    $("#email", second).focus();
    status = 'N';
}
else {
    status = 'Y';
};

if( message == '' ){
    alert("Please enter your message");
    $("#message", third).focus();
    status = 'N';
}
else{
    status = 'Y';
};

if( status == 'Y'){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {name:name, email:email, phone:phone, message:message},
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $("message_span").html(data);
                               // show response from the php script.
        }

};
```

So my problem is that I want the .focus() to focus on the text area which is not filled in ascending order, which is not happening, which is why I'm using the first, second .. parameters.

Now the second problem is that the ajax is not giving me a pop up of "message sent successfully" which is there in my php code

My php code:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$to='myemail';
$subject='Form Submition';
$message='Name: '.$name.'\n Phone: '.$phone.'\n Wrote the following messsage \n\n'.$message;
$headers='From: '.$email;
echo 'Message successfully sent';
```

Any help is much appreciated and I'm sorry if this question was asked before but I wasn't able to find it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to help you out. Try it:

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {

  var status = 'Y';
  if ($("#name").val() == '') {
    alert("Please enter your name");
    $("#name").focus();
    status = 'N';
    return false;
  }

  /*  if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      $("#email").focus();
      status = 'N';
    }
  */
  if ($("#message").val() == '') {
    alert("Please enter your message");
    $("#message").focus();
    status = 'N';
    return false;
  }

  if (status == 'Y') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        message: message
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $("message_span").html(data);
        // show response from the php script.
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='name' />
<input type='text' id='message' />


<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot for your help!